# Custom Validation Check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have following Model for the Leave. What I am trying to do is to check the number of leave available based on taken leave type, numbers of leave taken and leave allocation. It seems like my 'check_leave' is not getting validated for some reason without any error. Appreciate any help!

```
class Leave < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :staff
  validates :staff, :leave_type, :start_date, :end_date, :number_of_days, :approved_by, presence: true
  enum leave_type: {Medical: 0, Annual: 1, Urgent: 3, "Birth Leave": 4}
  validate :check_leave, if: -> {self.number_of_days.present?}

protected

  def check_leave
    if self.leave_type == 0
      if ( self.number_of_days = self.number_of_days + LeaveAllocation.last.medical_leave_counter ) > LeaveAllocation.last.medical_leave
        self.errors.add(:number_of_days, "Days exceeded the limit")
      end
    elsif self.leave_type == 1
      if ( self.number_of_days = self.number_of_days + LeaveAllocation.last.annual_leave_counter ) > LeaveAllocation.last.annual_leave
        self.errors.add(:number_of_days, "Days exceeded the limit")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Errors?  Improper results?  Please give output from the implementation, and then expected output that shows how to identify that when it's working.

Comment: It doesn't validate the check_leave at all. No error

Comment: Are you saying that `validate` doesn't *call* your `check_leave` method?  OR are you saying that there's a logic problem in `check_leave` that's causing it to fail validations?  OR are you saying that there's a logic problem in `check_leave` that's causing it to pass validations when it should not?  OR is there another problem that I'm not able to guess?

Comment: It calls the check_leave but it's passing the validations when it shouldn't. Will be great if you can help me check my conditional statement and see whether there's any error. Thanks

Comment: I see 2 things that I question: 1) use of self.errors.add is anachronistic.  It should be errors.add, and if you have a conflict somewhere, that's something to seriously look into.  2) `self.number_of_days = self.number_of_days + LeaveAllocation.fieldname` seems to not do what you would think.  It increments  self.number_of_days by the leave_counter each time you validate.  Side effects like this aren't expected in validations.

Comment: Have you tried using gems like pry to debug your code and see whether all the conditions are met to add an error?

Comment: What I really want to do is - check whether the sum of number_of_days and *_leave_counter are less than *_leave in LeaveAllication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you just need to remove the assignment of self.number_of_days in your conditions (both of them).  If I understand what you're looking for, this should do it:

```
def check_leave
  if self.leave_type == 0
    if (self.number_of_days + LeaveAllocation.last.medical_leave_counter) > LeaveAllocation.last.medical_leave
      errors.add(:number_of_days, "Days exceeded the limit")
    end
  elsif self.leave_type == 1
    if (self.number_of_days + LeaveAllocation.last.annual_leave_counter) > LeaveAllocation.last.annual_leave
      errors.add(:number_of_days, "Days exceeded the limit")
    end
  end
end
```

I also removed the `self.` from `errors.add`, as there's no reason to have it.  You can probably remove all of the uses of `self.` in this method, but I'll leave that to you, in case there are conflicts that I'm not aware of.

I created a short test program to test the conditions with some representative data that I created.  The test program is here:

```
test_data = [
  { leave_type: 0, number_of_days:  2, leave_counter: 2, leave_limit: 13, result: true },
  { leave_type: 0, number_of_days: 12, leave_counter: 2, leave_limit: 13, result: false },
  { leave_type: 0, number_of_days: 12, leave_counter: 2, leave_limit: 14, result: true },
  { leave_type: 1, number_of_days:  5, leave_counter: 1, leave_limit:  9, result: true },
  { leave_type: 1, number_of_days: 12, leave_counter: 2, leave_limit: 13, result: false },
  { leave_type: 1, number_of_days: 12, leave_counter: 2, leave_limit: 14, result: true },
]

def check_leave(leave_type, number_of_days, leave_counter, leave_limit)
  if leave_type == 0
    if (number_of_days + leave_counter) > leave_limit
      return false
    end
  elsif leave_type == 1
    if (number_of_days + leave_counter) > leave_limit
      return false
    end
  end

  return true
end

test_data.each_with_index do |test, i|
  puts "#{check_leave(test[:leave_type], test[:number_of_days], test[:leave_counter], test[:leave_limit]) == test[:result] ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'}: #{i}"
end
```

The results are here:

```
Pass: 0
Pass: 1
Pass: 2
Pass: 3
Pass: 4
Pass: 5
```

This is 6 specific test conditions that confirm the following 3 conditions for each of the 2 leave_types:

- (number_of_days + leave_counter) < leave_limit (expect validation to pass)
- (number_of_days + leave_counter) > leave_limit (expect validation to fail)
- (number_of_days + leave_counter) == leave_limit (expect validation to pass)

This indicates that the checks are working.  A failure to validate when expected is almost certainly because of bad test data.  Any one of the 4 fields used in this validation may be bad:

- leave_type
- number_of_days
- leave_counter
- leave_limit

The only remaining step is to confirm the data used in the application testing for the validations that are reportedly not working.  At least one set of test data (values for the 4 required fields) is necessary to continue any further.

Comment: Thanks but it's still passing everything when it shouldn't be (except blank)

Comment: I can only code blindly without knowing what information you're testing with and what you expect as a result.  For instance, with inputs of `leave_type = 0` and `number_of_days = 9`, `medical_leave_counter = 4`, and `medical_leave = 23448`, the expected result is a failed validation.  Or something like that.  So much of this is dependent on what data you have in your database, and there's no way for me to be able to figure out what will work and what won't without knowing results from known inputs.  Multiple examples are needed, both for passing and failing validations.

Comment: If the sum of `number_of_days` and `medical_leave_counter`  is more than `medical_leave`, it should fail and show error.

Comment: I understand that's the algorithm.  With the test data that you're using, it's not working.  I have updated my answer with a test program that works in all cases that I know to test.  If you aren't getting the results, I need to see the precise values for the 4 fields identified in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, since the leave_type is a hash you need to provide the correct key to get the value...

Change

```
  if self.leave_type == 0
  ...
  elsif self.leave_type == 1
  ...
  end
```

to

```
  if self.leave_type[:Medical] == 0
  ...
  elsif self.leave_type[:Annual] == 1
  ...
  end
```

Comment: I get TypeError no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer